# WCF response is truncated when calling through web server

Tags: c#, wcf

There is a webservice (that I don't control) that returns a large response.  In a simple console application the call to the service returns of the expected data.  However when I do the same in a web application, some of the data is missing.

If I serialize the response and write it to a file, one file is 215mb and the other 117mb (they should be the same size).

The web service bug occurs both on my local maching and on the production web server.

**No errors are being thrown**.  I have run a `WCF` trace and is shows no errors or warnings.  There is nothing logged in the event log.

The <`system.serviceModel>` config section is exactly the same between the two applications.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
              <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Service" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://myService/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Service" contract="MyService.Service"
                name="WSHttpBinding_Service">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You mean that the 117mb should be 215mb?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Yes, question has been editied for clarity

Comment: Maybe obvious question but could you show some code? Is the code on both sides identical? Is there a page timeout on the webserver? Is the content really truncated, or differs it somewhere?

Comment: I can't really post any code since it is very specific to our business (sorry) but it is just a simple WCF call to a method and the code between the two clients is exactly the same.

Comment: When I run the web app locally it runs as my current ID (through IIS Express).

Comment: New info, when i try to run this through WCFTestClient - I get an out of memory exception  :-(

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

- If the data was getting truncated you would have a malformed xml, which Would result in an exception.
- If the web server was not using the correct config file and it did not allow the size of response you would get an exception.

In both of the above cases you would not be able to serialize the result.

So you are getting a wellformed xml back, but it is a different size. Then there are 2 possibilities:

- A difference in the encoding, that affects the size
- A difference in the request parameters, that affects what is returnned